# How to export a specific environment of an agent Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

A new feature of dialogflow has been released which is Environments. I was wondering how can i now export a specific environment of an agent via the export api? is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, [it's only possible to export the current draft version of the agent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent/export).

That's a great point, though - I would definitely share that feedback with the Dialogflow team!

Answer (score 0):

You can [load a version to draft](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions#load_a_previous_version_to_draft), then [export it](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-settings#export).